# Сортировка List<T> по нескольким полям c учётом приоритета

Tags: c#, сортировка

Имеется `List<T>`, где `T` является каким-то классом с полями. Также имеется класс, содержащий параметры сортировки:

```
public class Sort
{
    public String Property { get; set; }
    public String Direction { get; set; }
}
```

`Property` указывает по какому полю будет осуществляться сортировка, а `Direction` указывает по возрастанию или убыванию (реально принимает значение `"ASC"` или `"DSC"`)

Имеется метод, с сигнатурой

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Sort[] sort)
```

В массиве `Sort[]` чем меньше индекс элемента, тем выше его приоритет.

Хочется понять как можно осуществить сортировку по нескольким полям (больше двух), притом что явно не понятно в каком направлении и какое количество полей будет использоваться. Иными словами нельзя написать

```
items.OrderBy(...).ThenBy(...)
```

Для извлечения свойств из типа `T` используется `typeof(T).GetProperty(sort[i].Property)`

Comment: А тип полей фиксирован? Если да, то проще.

Comment: Добавь пример реализации `Sort<T>` которая есть сейчас

Comment: @VladD поля либо int, либо string, либо long

Comment: @Grundy текущая реализация метода `Sort<T>` сортировала только по первому свойству из массива `Sort[]`, поэтому она как-то не очень вписывается в данный вопрос

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Примерно так:

```
public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Sort[] sort)
{
    IOrderedEnumerable<T> temp = null;
    foreach (var s in sort)
    {
        Func<T, IComparable> keySelector = GetKeySelector<T>(s.Property);

        if (temp == null)
        {
            temp = s.Direction == "Asc" ?
                    items.OrderBy(keySelector) :
                    items.OrderByDescending(keySelector);
        }
        else
        {
            temp = s.Direction == "Asc" ?
                    temp.ThenBy(keySelector) :
                    temp.ThenByDescending(keySelector);
        }
    }

    return temp ?? items;
}

private static Func<T, IComparable> GetKeySelector<T>(string property)
{
    var param = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T));
    var lambda = Expression.Lambda<Func<T, IComparable>>(
        Expression.Convert(
            Expression.Property(param, property),
            typeof(IComparable)),
        param);
    return lambda.Compile();
}
```

можно убрать if-ы и добавить чуть-чуть динамики, вроде поиска метода `ThenBy` по имени - но на скорость работы это никак не повлияет.

Этот метод не идеален: он упадет при попытке сравнить по свойствам с типом, не реализующим `IComparable` (но, например, реализующим `IComparable<T>`). Для обхода проблемы в общем случае придется

- или заменить в коде `IComparable` на `object`, получив боксинг при сравнении
- или перейти на `IQueryable` - свалив проблему построения фунции сравнения на провайдер Linq To Objects, как сделано в ответе Andrei.

`GetKeySelector` - это просто способ сделать `typeof(T).GetProperty(sort[i].Property)` без медленного рефлекшена.

Comment: +1, но: что если пользовательский тип не реализует `IComparable`? Имеет право. Не вылетать же на этом?

Comment: @VladD  тогда сортировщик, как и стандартный OrderBy имеет точно такое же право взять и упасть :) почем OrderBy можно вылетать, а кастомной сортировке - нельзя?

Comment: Стандартный сортировщик ж вроде делает не каст, а использует `Comparer<T>.Default`?

Comment: @VladD ...который успешно бросает исключение At least one object must implement IComparable. при попытке сравнить через него не IComparable

Comment: Насколько мне помнится, он сначала юзает `IComparable<T>`, если найдёт. То есть если тип реализует `IComparable<T>`, но не `IComparable`, ваш код вылетит, а дефолтный нет.

Comment: @VladD ок, да, придется править на некрасивый object

Comment: А сравнится ли тогда правильно?

Comment: @VladD да, но там будет некрасивый каст (хотя и сейчас не очень). Лучше просто допишу предупреждение в ответ

Comment: Угу, пусть лучше будет так.

Answer (score 3):

Кажется, это то, что вам нужно:

Сам метод будет выглядеть примерно так:

массив `Sort` нужно будет предварительно поменять, первый элемент должен быть `OrderBy`(`OrderByDescending`), остальные `ThenBy`(`ThenByDescending`)

```
 public static IEnumerable<T> SortIt<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Sort[] sorts)
    {
        var queryItems = items.AsQueryable();
        foreach (var s in sorts)
            queryItems = queryItems.ApplyOrder(s.Property, s.Direction);
        return queryItems.AsEnumerable();
    }
```

Ещё нужен экстеншен:

```
    public static class Extensions
   {

    public static IOrderedQueryable<T> ApplyOrder<T>(
        this IQueryable<T> source,
        string property,
        string methodName
    )
    {
        var arg = Expression.Parameter(typeof(T), "x");
        Expression expr = arg;
        expr = Expression.Property(expr, property);
        var lambda = Expression.Lambda(expr, arg);
        var method = typeof(Queryable).GetGenericMethod(
            methodName,
            new[] { typeof(T), expr.Type },
            new[] { source.GetType(), lambda.GetType() }
        );
        return (IOrderedQueryable<T>)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { source, lambda });
    }
    public static MethodInfo GetGenericMethod(
        this Type type,
        string name,
        Type[] genericTypeArgs,
        Type[] paramTypes
    )
    {
        var methods =
            from abstractGenericMethod
            in type.GetMethods(BindingFlags.NonPublic | BindingFlags.Public | BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Static)
            where abstractGenericMethod.Name == name
            where abstractGenericMethod.IsGenericMethod
            let pa = abstractGenericMethod.GetParameters()
            where pa.Length == paramTypes.Length
            select abstractGenericMethod.MakeGenericMethod(genericTypeArgs) into concreteGenericMethod
            where concreteGenericMethod.GetParameters()
                .Select(p => p.ParameterType).SequenceEqual(paramTypes, new TestAssignable())
            select concreteGenericMethod;
        return methods.FirstOrDefault();
    }
    private class TestAssignable : IEqualityComparer<Type>
    {
        public bool Equals(Type x, Type y)
        {
            return x.IsAssignableFrom(y);
        }
        public int GetHashCode(Type obj)
        {
            return obj.GetHashCode();
        }
    }
}
```

https://habrahabr.ru/post/181065/