# Сортировка в переменном порядке

Tags: c#, сортировка

Проблема, собственно, следующая: есть класс

```
public class Task
    {
        public int id {get; set; }
        public string title {get; set; }
        public int weight {get; set; }
    }
```

Далее имею `List <Task> Tasks`.

Хочу отсортировать их по двум из трёх параметрам, но порядок задать снаружи.

То есть, скажем, присвоить

```
int Sort_id = 1;
int Sort_title = 0;
int Sort_weight = 2;
```

И отсортировать сначала по id, а потом по weight.

Я умею сортировать в известном заранее определённом порядке:

```
SortedTasks = Tasks.OrderBy(t => t.id).ThenBy(t => t.weight).ToList();
```

Но мою проблему это не решает, т.к. мне надо задать порядок сортировки в зависимости от переменных.

Перебором и case'ами решать глупо. Вариантов слишком много.

Я хотел передать

```
string sort1 = "t.td";
string sort2 = "t.weight";
```

и как-то передать их в OrderBy()

```
SortedTasks = Tasks.OrderBy(t => sort1).ThenBy(t => sort2).ToList();
```

Но это, конечно, не работает.

Может, как-то иначе? Либо всё-таки научиться передавать в SortBy параметр, либо вообще всю схему поменять.

Я уже порылся в делегатах, прочитал [тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32592788/c-sharp-sort-list-on-custom-property?noredirect=1&lq=1) и [вот тут](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3309188/how-to-sort-a-listt-by-a-property-in-the-object?noredirect=1&lq=1) но что-то не могу сообразить...

Есть ещё похожий вопрос [в русской части](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620510/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-listt-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-c-%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0?rq=1), но там сложнее сортировка: у меня порядок только убывающий и всего-то порядок нужно выбрать.

Comment: @Grundy +1, сразу про него вспомнил)

Comment: Да, очень похоже. Я как раз его ковыряю, но пока у меня что-то не ладится. Лучше туда перенести обсуждение, чтобы не плодить сущности или тут помощи попросить?

Comment: UPD. Туда не могу. Репутации не хватает... Поэтому я тут напишу пока. @Grundy спасибо за наводку, но после public static IEnumerable<T> Sort<T>(IEnumerable<T> items, Sort[] sort) у меня ошибка, что класс уже содержит определение для "Sort"

Comment: А-а-а! Заработало. Как всех поблагодарить?

Answer (score 1):

С некоторыми приключениями, но [вот это очень похоже](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/620510/%D0%A1%D0%BE%D1%80%D1%82%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%BA%D0%B0-listt-%D0%BF%D0%BE-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8F%D0%BC-c-%D1%83%D1%87%D1%91%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%BC-%D0%BF%D1%80%D0%B8%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%82%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B0). Единственное, новичкам типа меня хорошо бы почитать про

```
using System.Linq.Expressions;
```

помнить, что класс Sort уже был определён, поэтому метод надо как-нибудь переименовать, и что возвращает этот метод список.